# Setting Immutable Flag using ioctl() in C

Tags: c, filesystems, ioctl

I have attempted to make a script that creates a file and then sets it as immutable similar to the `chattr +i` command for linux. **The script compiles** (with gcc), **runs** and the **file is created**. However the **file** itself **is not immutable and can be removed** with a simple `rm -f`. I have attempted to stacktrace where `chattr` is called and I found a function called `ioctl`. I then used what little information I could gather and came up with what I have below. I narrowed it down from `ext2_fs.h` but it just doesn't seem to work. I've clearly overlooked something.

**Updates to previous entry**: **Compiles** but **returns -1** on ioctl() function. **Bad address** shown with **perror()**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char shovel[16] = "I have a shovel!";
    fp = fopen("/shovel.txt", "w+");
    fwrite(shovel, sizeof(shovel[0]), sizeof(shovel)/sizeof(shovel[0]), fp);
    ioctl(fileno(fp), FS_IOC_SETFLAGS, 0x00000010);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think the `ioctl` succeeds? What about testing the return value?

Comment: Are you running as root?

Comment: Yes, running as root and still a return value of -1

Comment: In addition to @Jens consider displaying the error with perror, so you can diagnose what is wrong.

Comment: perror() returns Bad Address although strerror() returned a Segmentation fault and my server just went offline so I may be unable to provide anymore information until I get in touch with my host.

Comment: If you have to compile it before you can run it then it is not a "script".

Comment: Have you considered using the `chattr` command directly from the command line to verify that what you're trying to do can work at all?  Not every file system type supports extended attributes.

Comment: The chattr command was checked beforehand and was working. That's how I knew it hadn't behaved as I expected it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that the `ioctl` wants a **pointer to** the mask, not a direct constant. You have to define a int variable, store the mask (`0x10`) in it and pass its address as third argument of `ioctl`.

Also, I'd add some hints:

- other programs to change attributes are used to use low-level I/O directly (open, close...). Also, the file is usually opened with `O_RDONLY`.
- Use `FS_IMMUTABLE_FL` istead the raw constant.
- Get the current attribute mask first (`FS_IOC_SETFLAGS`) and mask it with the new flag, so other settings are not lost by the service.

Comment: Interesting. I was under the impression that `EXT2_IMMUTABLE_FL` was the correct flag, but `FS_IMMUTABLE_FL` seems to be correct too, and has the nice side effect of not requiring including `ext2_fs.h` (which can be a pain to find if you don't install the right packages). Nice answer!

Comment: That did the trick. I actually traced it back to FS_IMMUTABLE_FL myself and saw it was defined as 0x10. If I'd checked the manpage more thoroughly I would of noticed this and wouldn't of been in this predicament. Finally can sleep tonight without scratching my head.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the right ioctl command, but you're passing it the wrong arguments.

The manpage for `ioctl_list(2)` shows that `FS_IOC_SETFLAGS` expects to receive a pointer to `int` (an `int *`), yet you're passing it an integer literal (hence the *Bad Address* error).

The fact that you don't to any error checking whatsoever is also not helping.

The correct flag to pass to `FS_IOC_SETFLAGS` is a pointer holding the value `EXT2_IMMUTABLE_FL`, which is defined in `ext2fs/ext2_fs.h` (some older / different Linux distributions seem to have it under `linux/ext2_fs.h`), so you'll need to `#include <ext2fs/etx2_fs.h>`. Make sure to install `e2fslibs-dev` (and probably you'll need linux-headers too).

This code is working:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <ext2fs/ext2_fs.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char shovel[16] = "I have a shovel!";

    if ((fp = fopen("shovel.txt", "w+")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen(3) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fwrite(shovel, sizeof(shovel[0]), sizeof(shovel)/sizeof(shovel[0]), fp);

    int val = EXT2_IMMUTABLE_FL;
    if (ioctl(fileno(fp), FS_IOC_SETFLAGS, &val) < 0)
        perror("ioctl(2) error");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Remember to run this as root.

**UPDATE**:

As [Giuseppe Guerrini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289654/giuseppe-guerrini) suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32466931/2793118), you might want to use `FS_IMMUTABLE_FL` instead, and you won't need to include `ext2_fs.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char shovel[16] = "I have a shovel!";

    if ((fp = fopen("shovel.txt", "w+")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen(3) error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fwrite(shovel, sizeof(shovel[0]), sizeof(shovel)/sizeof(shovel[0]), fp);

    int val = FS_IMMUTABLE_FL;
    if (ioctl(fileno(fp), FS_IOC_SETFLAGS, &val) < 0)
        perror("ioctl(2) error");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the codebase. There was no error handling in the example because it was a part of a bigger codebase which I knew was working beforehand. I only shortened it to make it far easier t understand what I was trying to accomplish without flooding the topic with irrelevant code that would waste people's time. It is integrated and working perfectly as of now. Many Thanks.