# How do I chattr +i an open file descriptor in C?

Tags: c, linux

I want to make a binary that does the equivalent to chattr +i (immutable file) in C. I have attempted with ioctl() and had no success with it. If possible I would like it to be done without the need to include any additional libraries that are not installed/defined in a standard installation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char shovel[16] = "I have a shovel!";
    fp = fopen("shovel.txt", "w+");
    fwrite(shovel, sizeof(shovel[0]), sizeof(shovel)/sizeof(shovel[0]), fp);
    int immutable = FS_IMMUTABLE_FL;
    if(ioctl(fileno(fp), FS_IOC_SETFLAGS, &immutable) < 0)
        perror("ioctl(2) error");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

perror returns "ioctl(2) error: Operation not supported" when ran as root with global rwx on the file.

I have tested that chattr +i works on the command line. The file becomes immutable as expected.

Also the question marked as duplicate is my question on an account I no longer have access to. It's linked to one of many of my google accounts I created.

The script was tested on a friends server last night after my vps went down for maintenance. The feedback I gave on that thread was based on feedback from the friend over skype. What you see above is the results of my own testing on my own server.

Not a duplicate, the original was reporting "Bad Address"

```
-bash-3.2# cat /proc/mounts
/dev/simfs / simfs rw,relatime,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0

-bash-3.2# rm shovel.txt
-bash-3.2# ./1
ioctl(2) error: Operation not supported
-bash-3.2# lsattr shovel.txt
------------- shovel.txt
-bash-3.2#
```

Comment: `ioctl` is not a C standard function. You'll have to at least tell us what OS you're using.

Comment: Did you try closing the file *first*?

Comment: Closing the file would destroy the descriptor.

Comment: @melpomene right, maybe open it read-only would work? ... I was just guessing (obviously same as Sourav) because it doesn't seem to make much sense having a writable handle to an immutable file.

Comment: Putting it after fclose() results in "ioctl(2) error: Bad file descriptor" which is likely because the file descriptor is destroyed.

Comment: The code works as posted on my Debian system, as long as it is run as root and the filesystem the file is in supports the operation.

Comment: It opens with w+ to create the file and input shovel into the open file descriptor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Immutable Flag using ioctl() in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465756/setting-immutable-flag-using-ioctl-in-c)

Comment: At the time it was tested it on his server and I was giving feedback based on what he said over Skype. If you look at the answers I mention my server went offline. Today after a long sleep I awake to find my server back online where I test my script and find it doesn't work.

No longer have access to that account since a browser update and cookie deletion causing me to logout and me forgetting which Google account I logged in with.

Comment: If having the file open for writing interferes, then you could always use `freopen()` to replace the writable stream with a read-only one.  You would do that between the `fwrite()` and the `ioctl()`.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here @John Bollinger

Comment: I think the -1 is unnecessary and just prevents me from getting a clear answer to my problem. The issue of a duplicate thread is beyond my control as explained before.

Comment: Which file system and what mount options?

Comment: Any difference in `strace` between your program and `chattr +i`?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you done `chattr -i shovel.txt` before running this? How about testing without `shovel.txt` at all (i.e., let this program create it)? (Like said above, the code works for me as posted.)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 
`-bash-3.2# cat /proc/mounts
/dev/simfs / simfs rw,relatime,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /dev tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,relatime 0 0`

Comment: Your program works for me. I do suggest you retrieve the current flags and then set the FS_IMMUTABLE_FL flag, though, rather than just clearing all other flags indiscriminately.

Comment: @ShovelMan I suggest putting all relevant information in the question instead of hiding it down in the comments.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Not a duplicate. That one was reporting `Bad address`.

Comment: @davmac Sorry, I'm confused by your suggestion. Can you explain why that would make a difference?

Comment: @ShovelMan Then you'd know if the problem is due to not being able to set `+i`, instead of due to not being able to remove some other flag. Did you try my suggestion of running this without `shovel.txt` in existence, letting the program create it? This would also ensure no extra flags get in the way.

Comment: @Arkku I have tested with the file being created beforehand and chmodding to 0777 and also tried without the file being created beforehand. The chattr +i command works as expected.

Comment: What's the output of `lsattr shovel.txt`?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves `-bash-3.2# lsattr shovel.txt
------------- shovel.txt`

Answer (score 3):

The `chattr` command itself applies file attribute changes via a very similar call to the one presented in the question:

```
r = ioctl (fd, EXT2_IOC_SETFLAGS, &f);
```

where `fd` is an open file descriptor of type `int` and `f` is a flag bitmask of type `int`.  Its behavior differs in the following ways:

- It obtains the value of the flag bit via the macro `EXT2_IMMUTABLE_FLAG`.  I'm uncertain whether that expands to the same value that `FS_IMMUTABLE_FLAG` does (though I would be surprised if it didn't).
- It opens the target file descriptor directly via `open()`, with open flags `O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE` (or without `O_LARGEFILE` if that's not defined).
- It closes the file descriptor afterward via `close()`

(Based on e2fsprogs-1.42.12, `misc/chattr.c` and `lib/e2p/fsetflags.c`.)

That's drawn from a pretty recent version of e2fsprogs, yet the files involved do not appear to have changed in a very long time, so I'm pretty confident that the same source is applicable to your environment.  If the `chattr` program works for you, then that's the code by which it does so.  You should be able to do the same.

**Update:**

One other difference between `chattr` and the code in the question:  `chattr +i` *merges* the immutable flag with any flags already assigned to the file, as obtained via ...

```
r = ioctl (fd, EXT2_IOC_GETFLAGS, &f);
```

... and then sets the resulting flag set.  In case it matters, it performs this operation on a different file descriptor than the one on which it sets the flags, but one that it opens the same way.

I guess it's possible that your code is inadvertently trying to clear a flag that the driver will not permit you to clear.

Comment: If that's the case, why is it returning "ioctl(2) error: Operation not supported" when chattr +i works as expected?

Comment: If `chattr` works and your program doesn't, when run against the same file by the same user, then it stands to reason the the difference in behavior arises from one of the code differences I enumerated.  I'd estimate the file mode to be the most likely cause, but it could be that the FD being associated with a stream makes it incompatible with `ioctl()`.

Comment: I've tried all variants of *SETFLAGS and *IMMUTABLE_FLAG. They gave the same result "ioctl(2) error: Operation not supported". If it was due to the FD wouldn't that mean it would have the same problem across all OS's? A few people have reported it working on Debian.

Comment: e2fsprogs 1.42.12 -- from which the code I presented is drawn -- is the version provided by Debians jessie and squeeze.  It is the latest version available for CentOS 6.  I actually pulled the source from the Fedora 20 package.  CentOS 7 is actually slightly behind, at v1.42.9, but that's no different in this area.  They all use the same code.  It evidently works.

Comment: You could consider getting the e2fsprogs source package and building it yourself, to verify that the version of `chattr` you build that way works the same as the ones installed on your systems.  That would rule out (or implicate) a problem with your toolchain or build environment.

Comment: @ShovelMan it completely makes sense to try this exact sequence - open via `open` with `O_RDONLY` - etc - and see whether this makes a difference. Yes, your program worked for me as is, but then I have an ext4 filesystem and you have simfs. It's perfectly possible that they behave differently in this regard.