# Alternate method for chattr in Linux

Tags: c, linux, file

Is there any method to make a file immutable from a C program which is to be run with user privilege level on Linux? I have tried chattr but this system call requires super user permission.

Comment: @SteveSummit chmod is used to set file permissions. But it does not change attributes like immutable. I need the file to be immutable. That is the user is not supposed to delete the file.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: If you're asking about the `i` attribute, the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr) says that "Only the superuser or a process possessing the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability can set or clear this attribute."  So if you can give yourself the CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE capability, you don't need to be superuser.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would meet your needs, but if a user doesn't have write permission on the directory containing a file, they can't delete the file.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yeah. Changing the permission of directory makes the file undeletable. Unfortunately I cant change the permission of the whole directory. instead I need it for the specific file, if there is any possibility to do so.

Comment: And I suppose you can't put the file in its own, protected directory, because there's some precedent forcing it to remain where it is.

Comment: You can make a hardlink to the file in a different directory. The user could still unlink the file from the directory it's in, but the link could be recreated automatically. I don't know your real problem so I can't tell if that's a possible fit.

Comment: @user *Unfortunately I cant change the permission of the whole directory. instead I need it for the specific file, if there is any possibility to do so.*  That's one thing that the immutable flag is for.  That's what the OS already provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function called `ioctl`. You can refer to the following discussion on StackExchange itself. It poses a solution to a very similar problem.

[Setting Immutable Flag using ioctl() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465756/setting-immutable-flag-using-ioctl-in-])

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

To set the immutable flag you can either:

- Be root
- Have the `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` capability on the process

In either way, you can't do it with simple user level permissions.