# How to set immutable file attribute

Tags: linux, go, ioctl

How can I set the immutable attribute for a file with Go?

I need a function that set/unset this attribute on a file, similar to `chattr +i file`

I found this: [IoctlSetInt](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix#IoctlSetInt)

how to use it?

```golang
    file, err := os.Open("file")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
        return
    }


    err = unix.IoctlSetInt(int(file.Fd()), unix.PERF_EVENT_IOC_MODIFY_ATTRIBUTES, unix.STATX_ATTR_IMMUTABLE)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
    }
```

error: `inappropriate ioctl for device`

**SOLUTION**

I found a pice of code in [snapd's repo](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/blob/master/osutil/chattr.go).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you're using the right ioctl here... At least chattr and the solution of [Setting Immutable Flag using ioctl() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465756/setting-immutable-flag-using-ioctl-in-c) use `FS_IOC_SETFLAGS` (you can see what chattr does using `strace`). You can have a look at `/usr/include/linux/fs.h`, notably the big comment about "Inode flags", for more information.

Comment: While search for `FS_IOC_SETFLAGS`, found the solution, see aboeve. Thanks for the idea :)