# can i open file in c++ and make this file unmovable?

Tags: c++

I want to make my file with read only access, and cant be removed.

In linux shell, i can use `chattr +i` to make this file can't be removed by others.

and `chmod 444` to make this file read only

In C++, I find the `chmod` setting in `open`, but seems no chattr option.

can i open a file, and let it have this kind of access?

Comment: C++ includes C by definition. If you're looking for a C only answer, please say so. Hint: Look at the `chattr` source code for (platform-specific) implementation details.

Comment: `+i` only means "can't be removed by anyone but root", it doesn't mean "can't be removed". If that's your definition of "others", then sure.

Comment: @tadman the os code may be too hard for me. so, I cant achieve this by a simple system function?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: Maybe? It's in the `chattr` source. It may take some poking around to find, but once you do the answer will be self-evident.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465756/setting-immutable-flag-using-ioctl-in-c) might be relevant?